# Add History Log field to OOTB List

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

Currently I've a OOTB list. In that I need to add a field (multiple lines of text) to display the status field(custom field) value and who modified & when? It supposed to look like:

```
Work In Progress, User1, 01/11/2016
Process Done, User2, 02/11/2016
Completed, User3, 05/11/2016
```

That History field only get updated when the status field get changed. Currently I'm using SPD workflow to change the status based on the other fields changes. As of now I can set the field value with those attributes, but its currently overwriting existing text in the field.

Am I doing it in correct way? else pls let me know how to achieve that..

I'm using SharePoint online version.

Thanks,

Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the current value of the status column and add your new line to it. You can concatenate in SharePoint Designer workflows using the String Builder dialog

Your workflow will have something like these activities:

1. Set WorkflowVariable1 to Current Item:StatusColumn
2. Set WorkflowVariable2 to [%Variable: WorkflowVariable1%] "New Status Update Line"
3. Set StatusColumn to Variable:WorkflowVariable2

In step 2 click the "value" text then click the little `...` to open the string builder dialog.

Comment: Thanks Submits.. Its worked perfectly.. Also I have a doubt that I'm missing something like user profile provision, Date functionality etc., in string builder.. It is removed or I'm looking into wrong place??

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Currently, I've tried in following way and got a blank line in-between 2 logs. My current way: Var1 to store existing history log field. Var2 - to store current log. Whereas Var3 = Var1 Var2. So I again set Var3 to the change log field. But its add a blank line between existing log & currently saved log. Do you have any idea to remove that blank line?

Comment: You should ask another question for this one. It's possible the blank line is actually in `Var1` or `Var2`